# Binding a variable to one of two values with IF?

Tags: if-statement, rdf, sparql

In the following SPARQL query, I'm not sure how to use `if` to bind one of two strings to the variable `?result`. I heard that there are concepts of “in scope” and “out of scope,” but I don't really see the difference.  I've also tried putting the `if` clause in the `select` line, but it didn't work either.  How can I fix this query to bind `?result` to one of the two strings based on the condition?

```
SELECT ?result
WHERE{
    ?chain rdf:type rdfs:Property .
    ?chain rdfs:domain <http://www.vs.cs.hs-rm.de/ontostor/SVC#MDiskGroup> .
    ?chain rdfs:range <http://www.vs.cs.hs-rm.de/ontostor/SVC#IOgroup> .
    ?this ?chain ?arg .
    ?arg io:id ?var .
    IF(?var = "0"^^xsd:integer,
       BIND("    *"^^xsd:string AS ?result),
       BIND(""^^xsd:string AS ?result)) .
}
```

Answer (score 32):

The `if` operator in SPARQL isn't a *statement* as it sometimes is in a programming language, but rather is an "function form" for creating an *expression* (with special evaluation semantics).  The *value* of  `if(test,a,b)` is `a` if `test` is true, and `b` if `test` is false.  As the documentation says:

> #### [17.4.1.2 IF](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-if)
>
> ```
> rdfTerm  IF (expression1, expression2, expression3)
> ```
>
> The `IF` function form evaluates the first argument, interprets it as a
> [effective boolean value](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#ebv), then returns the value of `expression2` if the
> EBV is true, otherwise it returns the value of `expression3`. Only one
> of expression2 and expression3 is evaluated. If evaluating the first
> argument raises an error, then an error is raised for the evaluation
> of the IF expression.
>
> Examples: Suppose ?x = 2, ?z = 0 and ?y is not bound in some query
> solution:
>
> ```
> IF(?x = 2, "yes", "no")     returns "yes"
> IF(bound(?y), "yes", "no")  returns "no"
> IF(?x=2, "yes", 1/?z)       returns "yes", the expression 1/?z is not evaluated
> IF(?x=1, "yes", 1/?z)       raises an error
> IF("2" > 1, "yes", "no")    raises an error
> ```

So, `if` isn't a statement like it might be in a programming language, but it's simply a function (though lazily evaluated) that takes three arguments and returns a value.  SPARQL is a query language, and doesn't have statements that get executed;  it's a query language for matching patterns in a graph and binding variables to values.  So `if` is a function, and it just so happens that if the first argument is true, then it returns the second argument, otherwise it returns the third.  In general, you'd bind the value of a function to a variable with

```
bind( function(args...) as ?variable )
```

and this case is no different.  You'd call the `if` function and bind its result to a variable with

```
bind( if(condition,then,else) as ?result )
```

In your case, this means that you would use the following query.  I've added some newlines to help the readability, but they're not necessary.  Integers in a SPARQL query are shorthand for a literal with type `xsd:integer`, so I've also used (thanks to RobV's comment) `0` instead of `"0"^^xsd:integer`. (See [2.3.2 Matching Literals with Numeric Types](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#matchNumber).)

```
bind(if(?var = 0,
        "    *"^^xsd:string,
        ""^^xsd:string )
     as ?result)
```

If we actually want to shorten this even more, then we can use `xsd:string` as a constructor, and do (see [17.5 XPath Constructor Functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#FunctionMapping)):

```
bind(xsd:string(if(?var = 0,"    *", "")) as ?result)
```

This might seem a little bit odd at first if you're used to doing things like

```java
String result;
if ( var == 0 ) {
  result = "case 1";
}
else {
  result = "case 2";
}
```

but many language actually provide a ternary operator that lets you do the much shorter

```java
String result = (var == 0) ? "case 1" : "case 2";
```

instead.  This is the functionality you're getting with SPARQL.

Comment: You can simplify a little to `BIND(IF(?var = 0, "   *"^^xsd:string, ""^^xsd:string))` i.e. no need to explicitly state the type for the integer rather rely on the SPARQL syntaxes plain literal shortcut for integers

Comment: @RobV Ah, thanks, I didn't remember what the default number type was (whether it was `xsd:integer`, `xsd:int`, etc.).  If we're code golfing, then we can use `xsd:string` as a constructor, too, and do `bind( xsd:string(if(?var = 0, " *", "")) as ?result)`. :)