# Using condition in SPARQL query

Tags: rdf, sparql

I have a SPARQL query which is like this-

```
SELECT ?informationPath ?businessEntitylabel ?path ?sourced ?mastered ?delivered
WHERE {
?businessEntity dd:hasPropertyPath ?informationPath .
?businessEntity rdfs:label ?businessEntitylabel .
?informationPath dd:hasPath ?path .
OPTIONAL {
?informationPath a dd:SourcedData .
BIND("Yes" as ?sourced)
}
OPTIONAL {
?informationPath a dd:MasteredData .
BIND("Yes" as ?mastered)
}
OPTIONAL {
?informationPath a dd:DeliveredData .
BIND("Yes" as ?delivered)
}
} ORDER BY ?businessEntitylabel ?path
```

Now I want to have only one column instead of ?sourced ?mastered ?delivered and name is ?traceability. And the column will show if an ?informationPath is Mastered data or Sourced data or delivered data and accordingly I want to BIND ("Sourced data" as ?traceability) or ("Mastered data" as ?traceability) or ("Delivered data" as ?traceability)

I am new in SPARQL, and I was wondering if there is any 'if' statement in SPARQL which can be used as-

```
if(?informationPath a dd:SourcedData)
BIND("SourcedData" as ?traceability)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding a variable to one of two values with IF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116223/binding-a-variable-to-one-of-two-values-with-if)

Comment: SPARQL does have an `if` operator, and it's described clearly in [17.4.1.2 IF](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-if) in the spec.  In your case, you'd do something like `bind( if( …, "Sourced, if( …, "Delivered", if ( …, "Mastered", "Unknown" ) ) ) as ?traceability )`.

Answer (score 4):

### Using `bind` and `if`

I think that this is a duplicate of [Binding a variable to one of two values with IF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21116223/1281433), and I've marked it as such, but it might not be immediately obvious what the *conditions* in the `if` should be, so I'm adding this example as an answer.  Suppose you've got data of the form:

```
@prefix : <https://stackoverflow.com/q/22985157/1281433/> .

:x1 a :A .
:x2 a :B .
:x3 a :C .
:x4 a :D .
```

Then you can use a query like the following to get some results:

```
prefix : <https://stackoverflow.com/q/22985157/1281433/>

select ?x ?typename where { 
  ?x a [] .
  bind( if ( exists { ?x a :A },
             "type A" ,
             if ( exists { ?x a :B }, 
                  "type B",
                  if ( exists { ?x a :C },
                       "type C",
                       "unknown type" )))
        as ?typename )
}
```

```
------------------------
| x   | typename       |
========================
| :x1 | "type A"       |
| :x2 | "type B"       |
| :x3 | "type C"       |
| :x4 | "unknown type" |
------------------------
```

### Using `values`

That uses `if` and the `exists` construct to check various values.  Now, in your case, where you have  a specific number of cases that you want to check for, you can actually use `values` to simulate a sort of `case` statement.  To do that, you'd do something like this, although this won't give you an "unknown" case.

```
prefix : <https://stackoverflow.com/q/22985157/1281433/>

select ?x ?typename where { 
  values (?type ?typename) { 
    (:A "type A")
    (:B "type B")
    (:C "type C")
  }
  ?x a ?type
}
```

```
------------------
| x   | typename |
==================
| :x1 | "type A" |
| :x2 | "type B" |
| :x3 | "type C" |
------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Joshua Taylor's answer, you actually can handle the default case as well thanks to the UNDEF keyword:

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/22985157/1281433/>

select ?x ?typename where { 
  values (?type ?typename) { 
    (:A "type A")
    (:B "type B")
    (:C "type C")
    (UNDEF "unknown type")
  }
  ?x a ?type
}
```