# Part of a request depending on parameter type (if URI or not)

Tags: r, sparql

I'm creating an interface in SPARQL to query DBpedia.

For example you can search people who were born in Paris, or people who born in 1966.

My request is generalized and the value changes according to your choice.

According to my example above, here `variable1= dbo:birthplace` or `variable1=dbo:birthDate`.

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
?x a dbo:Person .
?x variable1 ?z.
}
```

I add a line to write the name of the place you want:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
?x a dbo:Person .
?x variable1 ?z.
?z rdfs:label variable2.
}
```

But this can work only if `?z` is an URI, which is not the case for date.

**Does someone know a way to make these 2 situations working ?**

I tried to add an `if` statement saying:

If `?z` is a URI, add the line `?z rdfs:label variable2.`
Otherwise check if ?z = variable2

But it seems that `if` statement works only to create a new parameter, in this example `?type`.

```
BIND (IF(isURI(?z),"URI","Not")AS ?type).
```

While I would like something like :

```
BIND (IF(isURI(?z),?z rdfs:label ?nameobject,?nameobject)AS ?nameobject).
```

Sorry if my question is not asked correctly, I tried to do it as clear as I could ..

**EDIT: Using `OPTIONAL`, thanks to Stanislav Kralin**

I tried with `optional`, here is my code:

```
SELECT distinct *
             WHERE {
?x a dbo:Person .
?x rdfs:label ?name .
?x dbp:birthName ?z .
OPTIONAL{ ?z rdfs:label ?nameobject .} 
OPTIONAL{BIND(?z as ?nameobject) .} 
BIND (concat("http://wikipedia.org/wiki/",replace(?name," ","_")) as ?wikilink) .
}
            LIMIT 100
```

So if `?z` is an URI, it gives the `rdfs:label`; if not (that is typed literal or plain literal with language tag), it should keep `?z`.

It does the first `optional` but not the the second one. However if I write this

```
OPTIONAL{BIND("Try" as ?nameobject) .}
```

it writes the "Try" statement. So I think I am not far from the solution, perhaps I'm not writing correctly the `BIND`.

Comment: It seems you need [`OPTIONAL`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#optionals).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I posted an edit about OPTIONAL, do you know what is the remaining problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, here is the solution! :)

Here is the beginning of my code :

```
SELECT distinct *
WHERE {
?x a dbo:Activity .
?x rdfs:label ?name .
?x dbp:skills ?z .
}

ORDER BY?x
LIMIT 100
```

My problem was that I needed to make 2 different queries according to the data type of my `?z` variable.

I tried to do it with `IF`, but as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116223/binding-a-variable-to-one-of-two-values-with-if), in SPARQL `IF` is an operator and not a statement.

So I tried with `OPTIONAL` by saying :

```
OPTIONAL{ ?z rdfs:label ?nameobject .} 
OPTIONAL{BIND( ?z as ?nameobject) .}
```

That means, if `rdfs:label` of `?z` exists, put it in `?nameobject`, otherwise, put `?z` in `?nameobject`.

But that didn't work, probably because of the different types of variables.

Finally my solution is to create 2 columns, to put the data in the same type, and then to put them in the same column:

```
SELECT distinct *
WHERE {
?x a dbo:Activity .
?x rdfs:label ?name .
?x dbp:skills ?z .
OPTIONAL{ ?z rdfs:label ?nameobjectURI .} 
BIND( IF(isURI(?z),"",concat(?z," ")) as ?nameobjectOTH) . 
BIND( IF(bound(?nameobjectURI),STR(?nameobjectURI),?nameobjectOTH) as ?nameobject) . 
}          
ORDER BY?x
LIMIT 100
```

And that works! I hope it will help someone else :)

**EDIT with COALESCE solution, from  Stanislav Kralin**

It is possible to simplify the code like this :

```
SELECT distinct *
             WHERE {
?x a dbo:Activity .
?x rdfs:label ?name .
BIND(STR(?name) as ?namestr) .
?x dbp:skills ?z .
OPTIONAL{ ?z rdfs:label ?nameobjectURI .} 
BIND (COALESCE(STR(?nameobjectURI),concat(?z," ")) as ?nameobject) .
}
```

Comment: OK. In many cases, one could use `COALESCE` instead of `IF(bound(...`. Also, you could use `UNION` from the beginning.